# CheckPoint SecuRemote behind ISA 2006

Tags: isa-server, checkpoint

Has anyone successfully got this to work? The VPN client uses UDP encapsulation and adds an 8 byte header to the encrypted packet, which ISA then strips out. the remote gateway then rejects the connection.

I have tried the NAT-T solutions but they don't seem to work. I have set the following in the firewall policy:

UDP 500 send-receive
IP-level 51 send-receive
IP-level 50 send-receive
UDP 4500 send-receive
UDP 2746 send-receive
TCP 264 outbound

I have also set some other ports but I think they are specific to this implementation. Does anyone know the exact settings that should be enabled on the client?

any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at visitor mode since that works on port 443 and should get through the ISA without any problems. But I am not sure if it is available in SecuRemote or if it is only in SecureClient.

CheckPoint [sk13187](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk13187&js_peid=P-114a7ba5fd7-10001&partition=Public&product=VPN-1) list all the ports need if don't already have a list.